# Removing <a> links with preg_replace but keeping <img> images inside

Tags: php, preg-replace, href

I'm using:

```
$this->tresc[$i][description]=preg_replace("/\<a .*\>.*\<\/a\>/i", "", $this->tresc[$i][description]);
```

to remove  links.

Sometimes the links are having  images inside I would like to keep:

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/page.php"><img src="http://domain.com/image.jpg" alt="​Image" align="left" /></a>
```

Is this possible ? Now everything beetween `<a>` and `</a>` is removed.

Comment: [Don't use regexes for parsing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: `strip_tags($content,'<img>');`

Comment: @spa - You'd use that function instead of your `preg_replace()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this:

```
$this->tresc[$i][description]=preg_replace("/<a href=\"(.*)\">/i", "",$this->tresc[$i][description]);
$this->tresc[$i][description]=preg_replace("/<\/a\>/i", "",$this->tresc[$i][description]);
```

But this is leaving text that's on the link.

Answer (score 7):

PHP's `strip_tags()` function allows you to specify what HTML entities you want to leave untouched.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

> You can use the optional second parameter to specify tags which should
>   not be stripped.

```
strip_tags($rssContent, '<img>');
```

That should remove/sanitize all HTML elements leaving the `<img>` tags alone.

---

The comment section of that page in the PHP documentation also contains loads of helpful functions that might be useful to you.  I recommend reading through them.
[This one](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php#107390) specifically looks interesting.